# Answer that only contains a link to jsFiddle

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, jsfiddle

jsFiddle is a great tool for live preview, however [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396859/javascript-slide-a-ul-down-to-last-element/5396921#5396921) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879311/javascript-event-execution-order/2879328#2879328) [lots of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819117/how-to-float-paragraph-next-to-image-without-wrapping-the-image/3819819#3819819) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885403/multiple-queues-in-jquery/2885482#2885482)[n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828442/full-height-div-inside-td/3828994#3828994)[swers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/95713/) that goes along this :

> Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/s0m3R4nd0mCh4r/

And nothing else is provided in the answer. Very often the code contained is fairly trivial and could be posted in the answer.

Should we edit those post to add the code in the answer? Should we simply ignore them? Is there any thing we could do to prevent people from adding answer like that?

Comment: Related: [May I edit a question with a JSFiddle link to incorporate the code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304331/may-i-edit-a-question-with-a-jsfiddle-link-to-incorporate-the-code/304424#304424)

Answer (score 32):

Downvote link only answers.

(If the poster whines about it, [read them the standard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Or the site was down and is useless as an answer that points to a door that leads into a brickwall.)

jsFiddle is no different and should be dealt with like the rest of them.

Rescue that code from the knuckled grips of that dumpsite and slap it back into the post where it rightfully belongs.

Otherwise we're only building another ghost town.

Comment: ZOMG BEST LINK TITLE EVAR! (Mouseover "read them the standard" to see it. No spoilers here.)

Answer (score 19):

If you're feeling generous, edit.

If you're not, downvote and comment.

If you're feeling cantankerous, comment and flag.

**Here is a comment template, to save you time:**

> Whilst this may theoretically answer
>   the question, [it would be
>   preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259)
>   to include the essential parts of the
>   answer here, and provide the link for
>   reference.

*Copy/paste version*

```
Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable]
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of 
the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
```

(Plug: If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might like [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/2116))