# My suggested edit rejected because I pulled in jsFiddle code

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, inline-code, jsfiddle

The following suggested edit, in which I copied code from a linked jsFiddle into a question but left the link to that jsFiddle intact, was rejected and one reviewer's reason was *"Do not inline jsFiddles"*:

Post: [Any event triggered on autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548533/any-event-triggered-on-autocomplete)

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/161353

I was under the impression that inline code was the right thing to do because a link can change or break. The following post talks about inlining jsFiddle code, but it's related to answers (the post I edited was a question):

[Should I edit posts to pull in the code from jsFiddle?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115056/should-i-edit-posts-to-pull-in-the-code-from-jsfiddle)

Are we not supposed to inline jsFiddle code?

Comment: Yeah, rejecting that edit seems like the wrong decision, I think.

Comment: Both rejection reasons are wrong.

Comment: I went ahead and edited it. It now includes every change you tried to enact.

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks. I wasn't sure if I should submit it again.

Comment: If you did re-submit, I would have approved it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the basic reason for the rejection was that you added a significant amount of content to the post when you brought in the jsFiddle. This made it appear to be an 'invalid edit' (as the other reviewer marked).

In such a case, I think I would try to carefully word my edit description to indicate that you are bringing in code that the original poster meant to be part of the post, and not just adding your own example. Not all reviewers might be aware of what a jsFiddle is, so it might not be immediately clear that when you "added" it in, you were actually maintaining the original meaning.

I do think it was an incorrect rejection, IMO. I just think that when they scanned it quickly, it struck them that you were "adding" an example which the original poster may not have meant.

Comment: Maybe *"Added OP's code from from sample link"* would have been better?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Sure, something like that would be better. I would have said something like "Included the sample code from the link in the answer." It's the reviewer's responsibility to be appropriately careful about their accept/reject votes, but I think it's good to be as plainly, simply clear as possible :)

Comment: @ThinkingStiff That might have been better.  Either way, that edit should have been accepted, so please don't be discouraged from inlining jsFiddle code into answers.  We want the answers here to stand on their own with outbound links only for reference.

Comment: Just a clarification on both your comments: It's the question that was being edited. The sample link was in the OP's question. But I'm assuming the same thing applies.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Oh, I was thinking it was an answer, for some reason! Yes... the same thing applies, definitely. It was still valid to bring that content in.

Comment: The same thing *even more* applies for questions, @Thinking, as then others with the same problem can actually find it when searching. Good edit.

Comment: What is the recommended way to deal with incorrect decisions by a moderator? I've only ever had one moderator disagree with what I've posted, and trying to discuss it with them only lead to an argument, and me frustrated enough not to post anything on stack exchange for a few weeks.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert That depends on the action, but generally I would say to let it ride. If you've only disagreed with a moderator decision once in over 3 years, I'd say that's pretty good. When you do disagree with anyone (SE Moderator or not), I find that the best question to ask is always, "Could you explain why this decision was made?", and genuinely try to understand the reasoning - even if you do not agree. Ultimately, as a Moderator, their opinion will 'win'. They are human and will make mistakes sometimes, though, and if you ask with the right spirit, sometimes you'll find a positive result

Comment: @Abhi, note that the reviewers are not what we call "moderators" here. Reviewers are users like you and me, with sufficient reputation to review. See [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) and [How can I appeal a rejection of a suggested edit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113727/how-can-i-appeal-a-rejection-of-a-suggested-edit)

Comment: Hm, considering there's no license on (most) jsfiddle's, are we actually even *allowed* to inline them?

Comment: @Deduplicator Quoting from other sources in context is considered "fair use", and thus not a copyright violation.