# Can I offer a bounty in the body of a question?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Is it acceptable to offer a bounty in the body of the question? I think it is, and I think it helps to drive answers to harder questions which may take a little longer to consider by letting the answerer know they will be rewarded.

Here is an example: [how to turn a string into a linq expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11479525/1026459)

Comment: I am more worried on the "_any answer with code will be upvoted_" part

Comment: @ajax333221 - I put a lot of code in there. It is reasonable to avoid conjecture as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reproduced from [the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141266/can-i-offer-a-bounty-in-the-body-of-a-question/141267#comment399750_141267):

It may encourage you to know that the length of this [waiting period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89678/should-the-bounty-waiting-period-be-reduced-to-24-hours) is a debated topic, but promising future payment within a question could lead to some vagueness about if an answer truly did help you and if the promised bounty didn't follow. IMHO. Better to avoid the issue, write welcoming questions, and/or wait for an official bounty.

And to add from Oded, welcoming questions (which aren't always rewarded with quick, helpful answers) will dramatically increase your chances. And hopefully you'll then have less need to reward bounties in exchange for attention/help from SO (or wherever this applies). I am constantly impressed by SO for it's quick response time regardless the promise of rep.

Answer (score 8):

If you insist on making promises to would-be answerers and imposing conditions on the community for answering your questions, the proper place to do that is in comments below the question, not in the question itself.

However, note that the social norms for asking and answering questions are largely determined by the community itself, and any attempt to bend those norms could be considered a turn-off.

None of us are being paid to do this; we are doing it because we like helping others, and maybe earning a few reputation points in the process.  So be gracious to your fellow community members.  And be patient; there's nowhere else on the Internet where you can get an answer to a good question as quickly as you can here.

Comment: The intent was not to impose on anyone in the community, but to show that a reward would be issued in appreciation. Many times OPs do not even accept answers.

Comment: @TravisJ - They don't _have_ to. This is an open community.

Comment: @Oded - I believe you misunderstood my point, and are now just being rude with your assumptions. Never did I state that OP's *have* to answer. "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved." -http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/178816.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bounty system - that's the only "acceptable" way to offer a bounty.

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/140505) for details.

If you wish to offer a bounty, offer a bounty, not promises that you will.

I actually find your wording somewhat offensive:

> Posting a link with no explanation will be downvoted. An accepted answer with code will be bountied, any answer with code will be upvoted.

You are certainly driving people away from answering the question with this tone and attitude - people know how the site works and informing people of the pending carrots and sticks does nothing but raise the hackles, at least for me.

Comment: "If you wish to offer a bounty, offer a bounty" - This is not always possible.

Comment: @TravisJ - As 4k+ user? Hardly. If you are not in a position to offer a bounty, for whatever reason, don't suggest that you will give one at a later date.

Comment: Do you mean, you have outstanding bounties or not enough rep to award a bounty?

Comment: @Ason - The OP certainly has enough rep on SO.

Comment: @Ason - I mean that there is a waiting period to offer a bounty.

Comment: @Oded - Your assumption is incorrect. I am not in a position to offer bounty because the system will not allow it that early.

Comment: @TravisJ - Are you truly is such a hurry? The answers coming in during the waiting period are not good enough?

Comment: @Oded - I am used to complex questions not getting attention. Many people just want quick rep.

Comment: @Oded - It is hard to post a question which already has many duplicates. The heckling is inherent in the site and rampant for duplicates, especially when they have accepted answers. I am not trying to drive people away, but to avoid answers which are duplicates or which mock my question as non constructive. Note that the accepted answer in the link here was not available in any other questions.

Comment: Complex questions that don't get rep is why bounties exist. There is also such a thing as patience.

Comment: @Oded - I have tried waiting before, every other time except the linked question. Usually it doesn't work. Dated questions don't get that much attention here.

Comment: @TravisJ If there is a duplicate question with an accepted answer then you shouldn't be posting the question at all, let alone debating adding a bounty.  If the accepted answer isn't good enough in your opinion then put a bounty on the existing question (which you can do since it's not brand new) asking for...whatever the current answer doesn't give you.

Comment: @Oded - Please review this post if you do not like the wording: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84345/178816

Comment: @Servy - Posting an answer as a link is not an answer in my opinion, nor in the opinion listed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84345/178816.

Comment: @TravisJ - It may encourage you to know that the length of this [waiting period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89678/should-the-bounty-waiting-period-be-reduced-to-24-hours) is a debated topic, but promising future payment within a question could lead to some vagueness about if an answer truly did help you and if the promised bounty didn't follow. IMHO. Better to avoid the issue, write welcoming questions, and/or wait for an official bounty.

Comment: @Ason - That is a good point and should have been in an answer instead of as a comment in my opinion.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. It is fine to downvote a link only answer. What I find objectionable is stating before hand the "conditions" by which you will vote. Voting is supposed to be anonymous, and, as I said in my answer, the tone simply drives people away, giving you less of a chance of a good answer.

Comment: @Oded - The community votes as well, keep that in mind. As the person asking the question, I am just trying to show that I will upvote when time is contributed because I value people's time. The community may vote as they wish. Also note: this was only tried on one question as a test and worked far better than any other approach I have used - which mostly includes waiting and often not getting a response.

Comment: @TravisJ - Well aware that the community will vote. As for the "experiment" aspect - a single data point does not a trend make. What I find most objectionable is the promise of a future reward in return for good behaviour - we are not children.

Comment: @Oded - A single data point does not make a trend, that would require a set of data. How is what you described different than the bounty system? Moreover, who is to dictate how one should vote? Each person votes as they see fit.

Comment: @TravisJ - The bounty system tells users that the bounty will be realized. No promises, no if and maybes. And **no one** should dictate how to vote.

Comment: @Oded - You just did. See this post on some dictation of how one person votes based on their opinions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/178816

Comment: @TravisJ - Again, you miss the point. I did not tell anyone how to vote. I am objecting to how you convey the message.

Comment: @Oded - I added parts of your answer to my own, and cited you, I hope that is alright. You make a valid point about welcoming questions.

Comment: @Oded - Your objection changes with time.

Comment: @TravisJ - My _objections_ are many.

Comment: @Oded - You object based on assumptions. Quick to assume, who is impatient? I find this line of comments to be nonconstructive. Thank you for your time.