# Please clarify the jsfiddle.net linking restriction in the error message

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-interface, user-experience, jsfiddle

The jsfiddle linking restriction gives you a popup:

> "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."

When I encountered that popup, I found it to be counter-intuitive and to require explanation.  However, to find out why the rejection exists, I had to: > try to copy the term from the popup (you can't right click > copy it) > do a google search > find a related meta question > and assimilate the reasoning in the meta question in order to understand the popup's point.

I really think it needs improvement to be very explicit about the desired behavior and why hoops have to be jumped through, which I would re-term as this:

> "Links to jsfiddle.net must also be accompanied by code blocks to ensure the basic code logic posted survives along with the answer."

Or a similar explanation of why additional action is required.  If language can be found that is clear enough enough, then perhaps the popup will stand on it's own.  If not, perhaps a link to a faq entry or the meta thread is in order.

Comment: It is pretty self explanatory...

Comment: I guess "code" is a little vague, but what did you think it meant?

Comment: I guess I wasn't explicit/specific enough myself.  I think the problem is not "what do I have to do to make it so that I can mechanically complete my answer post" but rather, why does jsfiddle.net specifically seem to be off-limits when in the past it was never an issue, and the stack-overflow code syntax coloring does not provide anything like the desired functionality.  My first thought, for example, was along the lines of "is there a problem with jsfiddle functionality that I'm not aware of" and my second was "so now I have to copy and paste code in two places, violating the DRY principle".

Comment: I'm not sure what question you read, but my understanding is the fiddle restrictions are so people don't have to click *yet another* link and visit *yet another* place to see your code.  That's just ridiculous.

Comment: I'm personally not adverse to the message change. It would provide a short rationale, which can indeed result in less frustration for new, well-meaning users. (The other, less-well-meaning users who caused that filter to be implemented in the first place probably won't read the message either way.)

Comment: That's an argument against pastebin or other code-only posting locations.  jsfiddle.net runs html, css, and js code.  And it does it well, in the same way that ideone.com runs sandboxed php well for explanations.  Stack overflow just -colors- code, so totally not the same level of benefit.  And the meta question (with status-completed) that I came to was here, though who's to say that others would find the same question if they wanted to know why the restriction: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: duplicate of: [When jsFiddle and other related sites are gone, so is the information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114942/165773) and [Answer that only contains a link to jsFiddle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84342/165773)

Answer (score 6):

Pretty much *no* error message explains why, and I've personally never run across one. When you encounter an error like "your username must be at least 4 characters" I'm sure your first though isn't "why?" Error messages are meant to explain *what you need to fix*, not to explain *why you need to fix it*.

If you really want to know why a website has certain rules because you're just curious, want to disagree, or whatever other odd reason, then go look it up, like you did. But giving a user a long line of text to read for a simple error seems even more counter-intuitive. That's like going to a retirement home and asking a simple question: "Well, sonny, way back in the day we did it this way because..."

Comment: I'm a developer, so yes, yes "Why" would be the first thing that I would think given a password length error.  And when my bank tells me that my password can't contain special characters or can't be more than 14 characters, I question using that bank, and when a development Q&A site makes it more complicated to use a code-running tool, I feel compelled to ask why.  Because if a rule is arbitrary, ... then it tends to lessen my experience.  I expect other developers will as well.  That is the problem here.  Without clarifying -why- in the slightest, it feels like a draconian/arbitrary rule.

Comment: The actual rationale behind the rejection is... ...logical, but the sparse rejection message just seems arbitrary and counter-intuitive and requires extra work without an apparent reason if no simple explanation is included.  *shrugs*

Comment: @Kzqai: You probably stand alone on that. A vast majority of users only want to know how to fix the problem so they can get through the process. Nobody wants to read a book to find out they just need to add another character to their username. They're meant to be short, concise, and to the point.